# Can you make one transaction on mainnet that initiates a transaction on a layer 2?

Tags: transactions, layer-2, bridge

I was going through some grants/RFPs and I noticed an interesting request. They are looking for a solution that allows a user to make a single transaction on mainnet to deposit funds into a protocol on Optimism. As far as L1 --> L2 goes, I'm really only aware of bridging assets. Can you make these more complex transactions (i.e. L1 -- transfer asset --> L2 -- deposit asset --> L2 Protocol, initiated by one L1 tx)?

Comment: This may be useful for arbitrum https://github.com/OffchainLabs/arbitrum/blob/master/docs/L1_L2_Messages.md#ethereum-to-arbitrum-retryable-tickets

Comment: Seems like the op just described how any generic bridge works. I don't see the special case that the RFP is requesting and it probably just declared that it is special in vain.